# Construct a vector space whose elements are sets

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I would like to construct a vector space whose elements are convex and closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

A natural idea is as follows.
For any two sets $S_1, S_2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, define the addition as
\begin{equation*}
S_1+S_2 \equiv \{s \in \mathbb{R}^n \vert s=s_1+s_2, s_1 \in S_1, s_2 \in S_2\}
\end{equation*}
and the scalar multiplication as
\begin{equation*}
c S_1 \equiv \{s \in \mathbb{R}^n \vert s=c s_1, s_1 \in S_1\}
\end{equation*} where $c \in \mathbb{R}$.
Apparently, the identity element is $\{0\}$. However, for most sets, the addition inverse elements do not exist. I was wondering whether there is any alternative formulation to construct a vector space for the convex and closed subsets in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Minkowski sum has cancellation property, so you can always embed your commutative monoid into its Grothendieck group, which is in a sense the best possible way to adjoint "negative convex sets":
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_group

Comment: You might find the concept of [support functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_function) useful. Their addition corresponds to the minkowski sum of convex sets, and similarly scale how you want. One can sometimes subtract them in a meaningful way, but I do not think you fully get a vector space. Note that their differences are still sometimes useful, for example in computing the Hausdorff metric on convex sets, but the resulting element of your vector space need not correspond to a convex body.